# How can I pass the values from one column into two columns in another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to programing and especially to SQL and I have one table called `team` where I keep the different teams and I want to show them on another table called `game` where it would have the `team1` and `team2` columns with the different teams.

This is for a school project and is to show the data in a website.

I tried with an `INNER JOIN` but that didn't work.

I already did something similar with the stadium, but the difference is that one is only one column and this one is with two columns so I don't know if it's possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY5bF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOtbv.png)

Comment: Please add the data to your question instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join with team table twice -

```
select * -- choose whatever columns you need
  from game g
      ,team t1
      ,team t2
 where g.team_id_1 = t1.id
   and g.team_id_2 = t2.id
```